# How to make a def inherit from another def,from the same controller Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, model

This is what i have in my gig controller

```
def downloadpage
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      if current_user.points >= @gig.pointsneeded 
        current_user.points -= @gig.pointsneeded
        @gig.user.points += @gig.pointsneeded
        current_user.save
        @gig.user.save
        redirect_to @gig.boxlink
      else
        redirect_to :back, notice: "You don't have enough points"
      end
    end
  end

  def success_download
  end
```

The `def downloadpage` ,makes the points exchange between users,when they make a purchase from each other.(i don't have buyer and seller) instead "user and current user".Now as you see i have `redirect_to @gig.boxlink` in the `def download page`,it redirect directly to the URL of the gig,after successful transaction.

I plan to create a page called "**success_download**",the view will have something like

```
yey you did it
<%= @gig.boxlink %>
```

and in `def download page` instead of `redirect_to @gig.boxlink`, say

```
redirect_to success_download_path
```

The problem is that @gig is not available in `def success_download`,but it is in `def download page`,

> how can i make the inheritance?

Comment: Where do you set @gig? Is it in a before_action?

Comment: you can also pass like `redirect_to success_download_path, gig: @gig.boxlink` from

Comment: @Nithin and in views/gig/success_download  use <%= gig %> right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where @gig is initialized ? Is it a variable of object in DB ?

Passing variables through different views via redirect_to is bad idea if these variables are crucial (e.g user can modify them and get the transaction sucessful without funds).

It's better to just render other partial on result.

`def downloadpage
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      if current_user.points >= @gig.pointsneeded 
        current_user.points -= @gig.pointsneeded
        @gig.user.points += @gig.pointsneeded
        current_user.save
        if @gig.user.save
         render partial:'successful', locals:{link:@gig.boxlink}
        end
      else
        redirect_to :back, notice: "You don't have enough points"
      end
    end
  end`

and in view use just `link` variable.

The other way is to use model that holds state of transaction and pass it's id in redirect. But partials will work well.

Comment: your method works,one thing i didn't expect is that the navbar disappear,the footer,body everything when i redirect to that partial,directly through the controller,all is a white page and the final link is in the middle of the page as i wanted.How would i show add the navbar,body,footer to be there as well? i guess they disappeared because it is not actually a page,but just a partial.

Comment: Sorry if i confused you,basically the payout disappears,i want it to appear,wit the @gig.boxlink,your method works,but the layout disappears.

Comment: Yes it's expected as partial will not render an layout. Use then normal render without partial to render whole page with layout and pass the variable to render specific partial in the download view.